# Which are the sports that are not based on outwitting the opponent?

Tags: trivia

Most of the sports are based upon winning by deceiving. Well a player or team can also win if another one doesn't play well but in the context of evenly matched sides its usually the one who deceives better wins. Sports like dart, archery and shooting are ones that are not based upon such notion. What sports do you know which is not based upon such paradigm but two teams/players play together at the same time?

Comment: Golf? [Match play](http://golf.about.com/cs/golfterms/g/bldef_matchplay.htm) (whether [singles, fourball, alternate shot](http://golf.about.com/od/beginners/a/matchplayformat.htm), etc.) is predicated on having a better score per hole than the other team/opponent. Bowling appears to be [another example](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/XQuXWSItmZM/0.jpg)...score higher than the other team/opponent. Suffice it to say, any sport in which *individual* results are compared to determine a winner.

Comment: But even where you don't directly interact with your opponent, such as golf or snooker or sailing, mental games and mental strength are crucial. You can beat an opponent without _doing_ anything to them.

Comment: The sport of rowing is a head to head competition. It's strength and endurance versus strength and endurance.

Comment: What about sports that just have judges like figure skating, diving, and gymnastics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the best example is the 100m dash.  Two guys running as hard as they possibly can, no head games.  Races that are longer may contain strategy (mental) games.

Comment: The head games are all *before* the race.